# Chrome App Page Scroll

Tags: google-chrome-app

There is no navigation in chrome aps using `<a>`. It is not allowing to navigate "in page" using #section1 as well. How to work around it?

Example below code works in a browser and when released as a chrome app it doesn't work. What is the work around?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section1">section1</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section2">section2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's completely clear to me what he's asking. It's well-known that there's no navigation in Chrome Apps via <a> elements. I didn't specifically know that this applies to in-page links, but I'm not surprised. The workaround is to handle the click on the "link" with an event handler, and then to scroll the page as needed with JavaScript. It's also possible that in-page links are allowed, but the problem is that there is no anchor (e.g., `<a name="section1"></a>`. Because of the hold, there appears to be nowhere for me to type this answer.

Comment: thanks @MarcRochkind I think I should have been more specific. I thought it would be such a common question in the google-chrome-app community that brevity might help save people time. Now I don't know how to go about removing the hold. I have edited the question above.

Comment: I have removed the downvote and cast a reopen vote. In my defense, the original formulation looked incomplete: problem described as "doesn't work", only the link part but not the anchor shown, etc.

Comment: Thank you @xan. Its this quality check work that keeps this place ticking for all of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking using  (or any other location-setting functionality) isn't really supported in Chrome Apps. The chrome.app.window you create() to whatever file is the one you're stuck with, and if you want to imitate navigation... you need to use DOM operations.

What that means for your specific use case is that to scroll to some element with ID "section1" you might add a click listener which executes document.querySelector('#section1').scrollIntoView().

Which is more or less what the first comment said.